# OWA add-in: Unable to fetch emailAddress

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

It has been observed that in case of some users `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` is empty. No email address is found using this. I'm not sure on which environment this is happening as I can only see these entries on my server log file.

Is this a known issue ? What might be causing `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` not return the user email address.

Comment: Is this happening only on Mac? Could you give us the Outlook version? Are you signed up for the Insider builds?

Comment: I can not confirm if this is happening only for MAC.But based on the errors reported by users, till now its affecting Mac users. I'm not sure about the version, I'll try to get that. Can't confirm if its the Insider build or not.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Can you suggest any alternative for `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` ?